# Python package location docker on singularity

Tags: python, docker, containers, singularity-container

I have a docker container and which runs a python script using packages installed from a requirements.txt file. When I run this using docker, the packages are installed correctly and are located within the container. However, when I try and run the docker container using singularity, it tries to access the python packages in the host machine.

I tried the following:

1. Using the --cleanenv flag made no difference.
2. Using the --contain flag fixed the package issue but when the files that I need to access using the --bind were no longer on the container.

How do I ensure that singularity uses the python packages within the container without breaking the --bind mount?